# Differentiation of an operator raised to a variable power

Tags: pseudo-differential-operators, microlocal-analysis

I am studying first order systems of the form
\begin{equation}
   L=\partial_t+K(t,x,D_x)\text{ where }D_x=-i\partial_x
\end{equation}
There is a change of variable and operator of our concern becomes 
\begin{equation}
  L_1=\big<D_x\big>^{-t}L\big<D_x\big>^{t}
\end{equation}
where $\big<\xi\big>=(1+|\xi|^2)^{1/2}$.

$L_1$ takes the form
\begin{equation}
  L_1=\partial_t+K(t,x,D_x)+\log{\big<D_x\big>}+A
\end{equation}
where operator $A$ corresponds to lower order terms.

My question is about the form of $L_1$.
How is it that $\big<D_x\big>^{-t}\partial_t\big<D_x\big>^{t}$ still gives a term $ \partial_t$? My calculations show only the term $\log{\big<D_x\big>}$.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We should look at operators as if they are acting on functions.
$\big<D_x\big>^{-t}\partial_t\big(\big<D_x\big>^{t}u(t,x)\big)=\big<D_x\big>^{-t}\big((\partial_t\big<D_x\big>^{t})u(t,x)+\big<D_x\big>^{t}\partial_tu(t,x)\big)\big)=\big<D_x\big>^{-t}\big(\big<D_x\big>^{t}\log\big<D_x\big>+\big<D_x\big>^{t}\partial_t\big)u(t,x)$